# Android can not copy db from Assets

Tags: android, database, copy

I have a question. I have 2 android projects. One is the "Main" project. The other is a project where I tried to implement a basic quiz application based on a tutorial found on the internet.

The quiz application works properly, so I would like to implement it on the "Main" project. (In the "Main" project I have got 2 packages, one is for the classes of the Quiz) I created the classes, layouts, copy the database to the assets folder. Everything is the same  as the second project. But it can't copy the database. I've got table not found error.

It makes the db, I checked it with ddms (pulled the db) but can't copy the tables. The code is the same(!) in the "Main project" as the second project. (And in the second project everything is fine)

Here is the code snippets:

```
package com.thesis.Quiz;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.thesis.eliminations.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelperForQuiz extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Androids default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.thesis.eliminations/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "QuizDB";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DBHelperForQuiz(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        //SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
        //SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
            //db = super.getReadableDatabase();
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            //db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
            //db_Read.close();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            //  db = super.getReadableDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //throw new Error("Error copying database");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        //InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getResources().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestionsList(int difficulty, int numberOfQuestions) {
        Log.d("NOQ",Integer.toString(numberOfQuestions));
        List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        Cursor c = myDataBase
                .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE DIFFICULTY="
                        + difficulty + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "
                        + numberOfQuestions, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Question q = new Question();
            q.setQuestionText(c.getString(1));
            q.setRightAnswer(c.getString(2));
            q.setAnswerOption1(c.getString(3));
            q.setAnswerOption2(c.getString(4));
            q.setAnswerOption3(c.getString(5));
            q.setQuestionDiffLevel(difficulty);
            questionsList.add(q);
        }
        return questionsList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class QuizActivityMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button bStart, bQuit, bSetDiff;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quizmenu);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartQuiz);
        bQuit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bExitQuiz);
        bSetDiff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetDiff);
        bSetDiff.setOnClickListener(this);
        bQuit.setOnClickListener(this);
        bStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("init", "initialize..");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bStartQuiz:
                List<Question> questionsList = getQuestionsFromDB();
                QuizGame currentQuizGame = new QuizGame();
                currentQuizGame.setNumberOfRounds(this.getNumOfQuestions());
                currentQuizGame.setQuestions(questionsList);
                Log.d("ql set", "ql set");
    /*  ((QuizApplication) getApplication())
                .setCurrentQuizGame(currentQuizGame);*/

                ((QuizApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentQuizGame(currentQuizGame); 
                Log.d("cqg set", "cqg set");
                i = new Intent(this, AskedQuestion.class);
                Log.d("i started", "intent");
                startActivity(i);
                Log.d("i started", "intent started");
                break;

            case R.id.bExitQuiz:
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.bSetDiff:
                i = new Intent(this, QuizSettings.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }

    private List<Question> getQuestionsFromDB() throws Error{
        int tmpDifficulty = getDifficulty();
        int tmpNumberOfQuestions = getNumOfQuestions();
        DBHelperForQuiz myDbHelper = new DBHelperForQuiz(this.getApplicationContext());
        myDbHelper = new DBHelperForQuiz(this);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            Log.d("openeddb", "open db success");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

        Log.d("ql try", "ql making");
        List<Question> qL = myDbHelper.getQuestionsList(tmpDifficulty, tmpNumberOfQuestions);

        Log.d("TMPNOQ",Integer.toString(tmpNumberOfQuestions));
        Log.d("ql rdy", "ql done");
        myDbHelper.close();
        Log.d("db cls", "closed");
        return qL;
    }

    private int getNumOfQuestions() {
        return 5;
    }

    private int getDifficulty() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the size of database?

Comment: Consider switching to [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which has the packaged-database pattern worked out.

Comment: I will try the SQLiteAssetHelper. But the other project the same (exactly the same) code is working fine :S

Answer (score 3):

In createDataBase() there is the following check;

```
this.getReadableDatabase();
```

This checks if there is already a database with the provided name and if not creates an empty database such that it can be overwritten with the one in the assets folder. On newer devices this works flawlessly but there are some devices on which this doesn't work. Mainly older devices. I do not know exactly why, but it seems like the getReadableDatabase() function not only gets the database but also opens it. If you then copy the database from the assets folder over it, it still has the pointer to an empty database and you will get table does not exist errors.

So in order to make it work on all devices you should modify it to the following lines:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
if (db.isOpen()){
    db.close();
}
```

Even if the database is opened in the check, it is closed thereafter and it will not give you any more trouble.

Comment: Where did this add on my helper class?

Comment: Same problem with Redmi Note 8 :) Thanks Tom from 2021